# Sorting a SAS data without creating a new data set?

Tags: sorting, sas, proc-sql

I have a hopefully simple SAS question.

I have created a data set `DATA1` using `PROC SQL; CREATE TABLE`, etc. In order to create it I ordered some data set randomly and took the first 100 observations.

I now want to reorder the dataset. This seems like it should be easy, but the only way I've found to do it is to make a completely new data set and reorder it. How can I sort DATA1 itself?

Comment: To make it so others can help you need to post sample data and examples of the code you tried including any error messages from the SAS log.

Comment: I posted an answer, but since there was no example data I had to make up the variable names to use the `BY` statement.

Comment: Thanks for the careful answer and your many comments.

Answer (score 1):

To sort a dataset in SAS you should use `PROC SORT`. If you do not specify an output dataset name then the default is to over write the source dataset.

```
proc sort data=data1;
  by var1 var2 ;
run;
```

Note that this will still require that the dataset be re-written, but SAS will handle the details for you behind the scenes.